# How to search entire dotCMS folder instead of given view

Tags: dotcms

I'm creating new content for our site and our images folder is fairly large (a couple hundred images). The "select a file" menu only shows 30 images at a time, and *only* those images are searchable, not the whole folder.

I would like to search the whole folder to save a significant amount of time on this project.

What I am having to do right now is search the view, if it isn't found, clear the search, and go to the next page in order to load the next 30 images, search that view, etc. etc., which is taking a very long time.

I have tried this on both Chrome and Firefox, and the same issue is occuring. Is there a way around this or is this a known bug?

Answer (score 1):

Right now there's not a way of looking at more images in the backend than it shows you on each page.

One thing you can try which might be easier is to access the image folder using webdav (http://dotcms.com/docs/latest/upload-and-edit-via-webdav), and then click on each image in the folder using your file manager (e.g. Finder on Mac, Windows Explorer on Windows, etc.) to see the preview of the image there.  You'll still have to click on each image to see it, but you can go through them pretty quickly that way without having to wait for the page to refresh.

*Note*: Depending on the file manager you use, you may need to load a plugin to enable you to preview all the images in the file manager.  For example, in Windows Explorer, you might want to install SageThumbs (https://sourceforge.net/projects/sagethumbs/) or the XNView Shell Extension (sorry, no link - not enough reputation to add it).